# Natural density implies Dirichlet density

Tags: number-theory

Let $M$ be a set of prime ideals of a number field $K$ . The limit
$$d(M)= \lim_{s\rightarrow 1^+} \frac{ \sum_{P \in M} N(P)^{-s} }{  \sum_{P} N(P)^{-s}}$$
Where $P$ is a prime of $K$ and $N$ denotes the norm of $K/ \mathbb{Q}$ is called **Dirichlet Density** of $M$. Also, the **Natural density** is the limit
$$ \delta(M)= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \# \{ P \in M :  N(P) \leq x\}}{  \# \{ P :  N(P) \leq x\}} $$

Show that the Natural denstity implies the Dirichhlet density.
Also, $d(M)=\delta(M)$.

Any help? I'm trying for days to prove this exercise.

Comment: What is Dirichlet density?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Edited! Sorry

Comment: @P.M.O. Are you familiar with summation by parts?

Comment: @ErickWong Abel's summation formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof when $K=Q$, for general number field proof will be analogous. 
$\# \{ p\in M :p\leq x\}=M(x)$. Let's define $a_n=1$ when $n=p$ prime, and $0$ otherwise. So, the sum

$\displaystyle\sum_{p\in M,\\p\leq x}\frac{1}{p^s}=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{a_n}{n^s}=\frac{M(x)}{x^s}+s\int_{1}^{x}\frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}}dt$.

Now suppose 
$\delta(M)= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \# \{ p \in M : p \leq x\}}{  \# \{ p :  p \leq x\}}$ exists and equals to $R$. That means by the Prime Number Theorem

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{M(x)\log x}{x}=R$ or $M(x)=\frac{Rx}{\log x}+o(\frac{x}{\log x})$

Now plug in this formula of $M(x)$ into above summation. We have,

$d(M)=\lim_{s\to1+}\frac{\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{M(x)}{x^s}+s\int_{1}^{x}\frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}}dt}{-\log (s-1)}$,

as, $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^s}=-\log (s-1) + O(1)$.

Now  using L'hospital rule we can have that,

$d(M)=\lim_{s\to1+}(s-1)\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{M(t)\log t}{t^{s+1}}dt$

So, $\displaystyle\\d(M)=\lim_{s\to1+}(s-1)(R\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{s}}+o(\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{s}}))$

We know that, $\lim_{s\to1+}(s-1)\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{s}}=1$ as $\epsilon\to0$.

so $d(M)=R+o(1)=R$

For general case just "switch all $p$'s by $N(P)$'s", and use [Prime Ideal Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_prime_ideal_theorem) instead of PNT.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any reference to the last limit?

Comment: Can you please specify which limit you are asking for?

Comment: You mean $\lim_{s\to1+}(s-1)\int_{1+\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{s+1}\log t}=1$? See, if you change variable $\log t =z$ you will get a form like $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-sz}}{z}$ which is like '$\lim_{s\to1+}\Gamma(s-1)$'. An you may know that $\lim_{s\to0+}s\Gamma(s)=\lim_{s\to0+}\Gamma(s+1)=1$. Please tell me whether this helps you!

Comment: Excelent, last question, I think. Why do $d(M)$ is written as $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}$ in the numerator? And, How is applied in the numerator the L'hopital rule?

Comment: From the definition if $d(M)$ numerator is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{p\in M,\\p\leq x}\frac{1}{p^s}$. There the limit comes. After operating the limit of $x\to\infty$ you operate the limit $s\to 1+$ by L'hospital rule as it is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form. Just calculate, there should not be any difficulties in calculation.

Comment: Thanks again, but I've been trying to understand, why the numerator is infinite to apply L'Hopital, I have this, $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{M(t)}{t^2} \,dt= \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{R}{t \log(t)} + o(\frac{1}{t \log(t)}) \,dt$. How I operate the little oh?

Comment: $d(M)=\lim_{s\to 1+}\frac{\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}} \,dt}{-\log(s-1)}$. Do you get this?

Comment: After applying $x \rightarrow \infty$, i get $d(M)= \lim_{s \rightarrow 1^+}  \frac{s \int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}}  }{-\log(s-1)}$, Right?

Comment: Right. You don't have to bother about $o$ part, just think $M(x)$ ~ $\frac{Rx}{\log x}$. Now you obviously get $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{M(t)}{t^2} \,dt$ diverges. Okay?

Comment: Yes, diverges. Now, last favor, i guess... What is the derivative of $s \int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}} dt$ I miss that step.

Comment: Im not sure, according to my calculations $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}} - s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t) \log(t)}{t^{s+1}} $

Comment: It is a shame that, I DON'T KNOW how to differentiate. And I made a big mistake there. Please forgive me and check the edit.

Comment: Applying LHopital i get, $\lim_{s \to 1^+} -(s-1)[\int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}}  dt- s \int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t) \log(t)}{t^{s+1}} dt] \neq \lim_{s \to 1^+} (s-1) \int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t) \log(t)}{t^{s+1}} dt $ What do you did?

Comment: Why are you bothering about the $s$ term. as $s\to 1+$ put "$s=1$" as it doesn't effect crucial limit part. But $\lim_{s \to 1^+} -(s-1)[\int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}}  dt- s \int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t) \log(t)}{t^{s+1}} dt] = \lim_{s \to 1^+} (s-1) \int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t) \log(t)}{t^{s+1}} dt$

Comment: I worry that you do not use $s=1$ in $-(s-1)$ and dont know what happen with $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}}$

Comment: No, I meant that your limit is like $\lim_{x\to 0}(x+1)\frac{\sin x}{x}$. What I was saying: Just forget $x+1$ part, as it does not affect limit.

Comment: Sure! And, what happen with $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}}$, no matter in the limit? or what...

Comment: What I am telling is get rid of $s$ at very first: $d(M)= \lim_{s \rightarrow 1^+}  \frac{s \int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}}  }{-\log(s-1)}=d(M)= \lim_{s \rightarrow 1^+}  \frac{\int_1^{\infty} \frac{M(t)}{t^{s+1}}  }{-\log(s-1)}$

Comment: $\int o(f(x))dx = o(\int f(x)dx) $?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: To the converse, you know where i can find the counterexample. I know that is the set of numbers that have 1 as first digit. Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid that I couldn't quite follow you in last comment!

Comment: Anyway, you've been a great help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not a problem! It would be appreciated if you kindly upvote my answer! :)

Comment: Hey, have you got solution of the example where Dirichlet density is $\frac{\log 2}{\log 10}$? This has a wonderful solution which was done by Bombieri in a private communication with Serre.

Comment: Not is clear to me the step $\int o(\frac{1}{t^s})dt= o(\int \frac{dt}{t^s})$

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to prove the theorem for $K=Q$. For general number field proof will be analogous. Let
$M(x)=\# \{ p\in M :p\leq x\}$. Now suppose
$\delta(M)= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \# \{ p \in M : p \leq x\}}{  \# \{ p :  p \leq x\}}=\frac{M(x)}{\pi(x)}$ exists and equals to $R$. 
Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{M(x)}{x}=0=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{x}$, the Dirichlet series
$$\sum_{p\in M}\frac{1}{p^s}=s\int_1^\infty\frac{M(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx,\quad\sum_p\frac{1}{p^s}=s\int_1^\infty\frac{\pi(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx,\quad s>1$$

In order to prove our theorem, we need a lemma.

**lemma**
Let $A(x),B(x)$ be non-negative integrable function and the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}=R$.
If
$$\lim_{s\to 1^+}\int_1^\infty\frac{B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx=+\infty$$
then we have that
$$\lim_{s\to1^+}\frac{\int_1^\infty\frac{A(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}{\int_1^\infty\frac{B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}=R.$$
**proof**

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}=R$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a constant $C=C(\epsilon)$ such that $|R(x):=A(x)-RB(x)|\leq C+\epsilon B(x)$ for all $x\geq1$.

Hence
$$\frac{\int_1^\infty\frac{A(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}{\int_1^\infty\frac{B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}=R+
  \frac{\int_1^\infty\frac{A(x)-RB(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}{\int_1^\infty\frac{B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}=R+
  \frac{\int_1^\infty\frac{R(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}{\int_1^\infty\frac{B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}.$$
  Hence, it suffices to prove
  $$\lim_{s\to 1^+}\frac{\int_1^\infty\frac{R(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}{\int_1^\infty\frac{B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}=0$$
  Since
  $$0\leq \left|\int_1^\infty\frac{R(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx\right|\leq \int_1^\infty\frac{|R(x)|}{x^{s+1}}dx\leq \int_1^\infty\frac{C+\epsilon B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx=\frac{C}{s}+\epsilon\int_1^\infty\frac{B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx$$
We have that
  $$\limsup_{s\to1^+}\frac{\int_1^\infty\frac{R(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}{\int_1^\infty\frac{B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}\leq \epsilon$$
  Hence
$$\lim_{s\to 1^+}\frac{\int_1^\infty\frac{R(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}{\int_1^\infty\frac{B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}=0$$
  and
  $$\lim_{s\to 1^+}\frac{\int_1^\infty\frac{A(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}{\int_1^\infty\frac{B(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx}=R$$
Now, the proof is complete.