# Dirichlet vs. logarithmic density

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

The *Dirichlet density* of A relative to B is 
$$
\lim_{s\to 1^+}\frac{\sum\limits_{n\in A}n^{-s}}{\sum\limits_{n\in B}n^{-s}}
$$

and the *logarithmic density* of A relative to B is
$$
\delta(A) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{a \in A,\, a \le n} \frac1a}{\sum_{b\in B,b\le n}\frac 1b}
$$

with the respective lower and upper densities defined with $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ respectively. ($A\subseteq B\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ of course.)

I have read in one source that the Dirichlet density exists if and only if the logarithmic density exists (in which case they are equal). In another source I read that they are the same. I wanted to check; to wit:

- Is the lower Dirichlet density always equal to the lower logarithmic density?
- Is the upper Dirichlet density always equal to the upper logarithmic density?
- Does the Dirichlet density always exist if and only if the lower logarithmic density exists?
- If both exist, are they equal?
- Do the above hold in the special case $B=\mathbb{N}$?
- Sometimes terminology is not standardized; are these definitions standard?

Comment: If $B= \mathbb{N}$ _Dirichlet density_ always exist for any $A$. But _Logarithmic density_ may not. If later exists then it must be equal to Dirichlet density. Not exactly your problem, but still you may look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437673/natural-density-implies-dirichlet-density?lq=1)

Comment: @Kunnysan Unless I've made a silly mistake, the Dirichlet density of $$A = \mathbb{N}\cap \bigcup_{k = 0}^{\infty} \bigl[2^{2^{2k}}, 2^{2^{2k+1}}\bigr)$$ relative to $\mathbb{N}$ doesn't exist. Up to a term tending to $0$, the $\zeta$-quotient is $f\bigl(2^{1-s}\bigr)$, where $f$ is [Hardy's oscillating function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198665/on-an-example-of-an-eventually-oscillating-function), according to my calculations.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Just to be sure : in case $B=\mathbf N$, does the existence of a Dirichlet density of a set $A$ implies the one of a natural density ? I suspect not, but  I found no reference on this on Math.SE. Do you know one by chance ?

Comment: @Olivier You're right, it doesn't. The existence of a natural density implies the existence of a logarithmic density, and that in turn implies the existence of a Dirichlet density (and as far as they exist, the densities are equal), but at least the first implication is not reversible (I'm not sure whether a Dirichlet density implies a logarithmic density). The set of positive integers whose decimal expansion starts with digit $d$ (no leading zeros) has logarithmic density $\frac{\log (d+1) - \log d}{\log 10}$ (and thus the same Dirichlet density), but no natural density.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$ \alpha_{n} = \sum_{\substack{ a \leq n \\ a \in A}} \frac{1}{a}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\beta_{n} = \sum_{\substack{ b \leq n \\ b \in B}} \frac{1}{b}. $$

The following holds:
$$ \varliminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\alpha_{n}}{\beta_{n}}
\leq \varliminf_{s\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sum_{n\in A} n^{-1-s}}{\sum_{n\in B} n^{-1-s}}
\leq \varlimsup_{s\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sum_{n\in A} n^{-1-s}}{\sum_{n\in B} n^{-1-s}}
\leq \varlimsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\alpha_{n}}{\beta_{n}} \tag{1} $$

It is clear that this inequality holds if $\beta_{n}$ converges. (In this case, the above inequality reduces to equality.) So we may assume that $\beta_{n} \to \infty$. Then note that we have

$$ \sum_{n\in A} \frac{1}{n^{1+s}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{n} \left( \frac{1}{n^{s}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{s}} \right) $$

and likewise for $\beta_{n}$. Thus if we put $\bar{\rho} = \varlimsup \alpha_{n} / \beta_{n}$, for $\epsilon > 0$ we can find $N$ such that $\alpha_{n} < (\bar{\rho} + \epsilon) \beta_{n}$ for $n > N$. Thus

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\in A} \frac{1}{n^{1+s}}
&\leq \sum_{n\leq N} \alpha_{n} \left( \frac{1}{n^{s}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{s}} \right) + \sum_{n>N} (\bar{\rho} + \epsilon) \beta_{n} \left( \frac{1}{n^{s}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{s}} \right) \\
&= \sum_{n\leq N} (\alpha_{n} - (\bar{\rho} + \epsilon) \beta_{n}) \left( \frac{1}{n^{s}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{s}} \right) + (\bar{\rho} + \epsilon) \sum_{n\in B} \frac{1}{n^{1+s}} \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Dividing both sides of $(2)$ by $ \sum_{n\in B} n^{-1-s} $ and taking $s \to 0^{+}$, we have

$$ \varlimsup_{s\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sum_{n\in A} n^{-1-s}}{\sum_{n\in B} n^{-1-s}}
\leq \bar{\rho} + \epsilon. $$

Here, we exploited the fact that

$$ \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \sum_{n\in B} \frac{1}{n^{1+s}} = \sum_{n\in B} \frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \beta_{n} = \infty $$

so that the $\sum_{n \leq N}$ part of the sum $(2)$, divided by $ \sum_{n\in B} n^{-1-s} $, vanishes as $s \to 0^{+}$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we obtain the rightmost part of the inequality $(1)$. Similar consideration proves another side, completing the proof.

Kunnysan showed that $(1)$ need not reduce to an equality, hence this is not far from the sharpest result.